# Saving videos doesnt work in opencv2-python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to run this example code for saving a video:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It shows the video without problems, but 'output.avi' is only a 100kb file that cannot be opened with any video player.
I tried changing the codec from *'XVID'. I tried at least a 100 different codec types from http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php with the same result. I ran out of ideas unfortunately. 
How can i solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenCV 2.4.X, you’ll need to change 
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

function to 
    cv2.cv.FOURCC(*'XVID') .

Comment: cv2 doesn't have a cv module in opencv 3.0

Comment: Correct thats why i said for Opencv 2.4.X since you mentioned OpenCV2-python in title. If you are using OpenCV 3 then its right path. May be try with .avi codec or some other codec. here is a good blog to start with  http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/

Comment: Thank you, the site that you linked helped me resolve the problem.

Comment: So here is what i had to change in the original code to make it work:
1. because 'input.mp4' file is a colored video, i had to change this
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
into this
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), isColor=True)

2. The resolution that i specified didn't match the actual video resolution.

3. In order to save the output as .avi, the 'MJPG' codec should be used instead of 'XVID'